Amiga 500 left mouse button is not working. How to diagnose and fix it?
I've recently bought a Amiga 500 (A6 board). This Amiga works perfectly and starts as it should, except for the fact that when I hover on a icon and click my left mouse button to open it, it doesn't respond.
I'm almost certain that this is not a problem with my mouse, because of my 2 joystick's buttons, only 1/2 works.
If more information is needed, for example: the voltage on a certain pin, I can provide it.

Amiga mice are known for their notoriously failing buttons. And it's in fact really the switches, normally. Does it at least work sometimes?

@tofro Sadly, it has not yet worked (and I tried a lot), leading me all the more to believe that this is not just the mouse's switches. Tho I will look for a replacement, just to make sure.

Not familiar with Amiga too much, but I did have an Atari mouse recently that needed a replacement button. Found one in a cheapo pack of "Arduino bits" I'd bought that had buttons LEDs etc. included. Also I know the Amiga doesn't have the sucky ports of the Atari (underneath) but the Atari ones are known for getting broken solder joints. Might be worth reflowing the solder on the connectors?

@MathijsKlaver What fixed it? It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question (and accept your own answer)

My Amiga mouse had some weird switches held together with sticky tape. After cleaning the button's contacts with some alcohol they make contact again and work!

In case you can really verify(*) it's not the button switch (which is the most likely culprit), the next possible cause of failure is the 8520 CIA - There's not much else in-between. Luckily, the Amiga has two of them - To verify this is the problem, you can simply swap U7 and U8 - The fault should move from the mouse to the serial interface.
(*)You can try and connect the pins 6 and 8 on CN1  - This should generate a left button click
